# Dynamic Sender Profile Emails not received properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have the variables(@FromEmail and @FromName) printing in my email body properly, but when I send the email it defaults back to my defaul From Email and Name.

I have this code in my Sender Profile:

```
%%[ ContentBlockbyKey("DynamicFromName") ]%% %%=v(@FromName)=%%
```

and

```
%%[ ContentBlockbyKey("DynamicFromEmail") ]%% %%=v(@FromEmail)=%%
```

The final email displays the correct output of the variables, but my From name and from email are the defaults and not dynamic variables.

Comment: Firstly, do you have Enhanced Sender Profiles enabled for you to use AMPScript in your sender profiles? Secondly, you have a space between where your content block executes and the outputting of the @FromName variable. Lastly, Content Builder tends to place extraneous HTML code around what's returned by ContentBlockByKey. Place your code in a "Code" block in Content Builder, not "Text", "HTML" or other and call it using ContentBlockById.

Comment: Thanks that worked!